# Rails joint table custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm new to Rails and here's my current situation: I have a joint table of users and teams they belong to, all teams have an attribute called organization_id, I want to make sure that I can't add a user to the table such that there's an existing entry in the table with the same user and it has the same organization_id as the new one, i.e. if I have an entry (michael, team_rupert) and team_rupert's organization_id is 1, I can't add an entry (michael, team_andrew), where team_andrew's organization_id is also 1. Here's what my mentor and I scraped together as a custom test, but it doesn't seem to work

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  validate :user_can_only_be_in_one_team_per_organization
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :team_id

  def user_can_only_be_in_one_team_per_organization
    organizations = self.user.organizations

    organization_ids = organizations.pluck :id
    unique_organization_ids = organization_ids.uniq

    if organization_ids.count != unique_organization_ids.count
      errors.add :user, 'can\'t be in two teams in the same organization'
    end
  end
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
  has_many :organizations, through: :teams

  validates :username, presence: true,
                       uniqueness: true
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams
  has_many :memberships, through: :teams
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   uniqueness: true
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships

  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  belongs_to :organization

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   uniqueness: true
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I managed to fix it, it turns out the new values are not yet added to the table, so the if statement should check if our current organization_id is in the organization_id array.

Comment: I'm confused.  If team rupert has an organization_id of 1, team andrew's organization id won't be 1.  Do you mean you want to avoid duplicates in the join table?

Comment: Please add your models and their associations to the questions so that its easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Organizations can have many teams and teams can have many users, sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're validating things in the user model, and I'm guessing that you have the appropriate User/Teams relationships set up. If so, could you do something like the following:

```
def user_can_only_be_in_one_team_per_organization
  teams_in_organization = self.teams.where(organization_id: organization_id) 

  if teams_in_organization.any? 
    errors.add :user, 'can\'t be in two teams in the same organization'
  end
end
```